# Sails js : calling store procedure which returns two datatable in a dataset

Tags: javascript, sql-server, json, node.js, sails.js

I am using Sails JS on server side where I make hit in sql data base using Store procedure which returns me two data table in a data set in a single call. But when sails return a JSON Data its have only the data of the first data table other data table is not including in a JSON data. Can any body help me over that ?

Comment: are you using temporary tables?, are you making the SELECT's inside the sp?

Comment: Ya its using select query inside it.

Comment: have you tried using the selects and the sp separatedly?